# Lambda Expression without Argument

Tags: c#, delegates, action, anonymous-delegates

Assuming I have a method like this (my actual method does more—I've simplified the code here):

```
protected void Run(Action a)
{
    a();
}
```

I can then call it with code like this:

```
Run(myAction);
```

But how would I create an inline method to pass arguments to my action. The following code produces an *invalid argument* error:

```
Run(myAction(arg1, arg2));
```

I'm accustomed to doing this with actions that are passed an argument using a lambda expression like `arg => myAction(arg)`, but here no argument is passed. So what would be the proper syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Run(()=>myAction(arg1, arg2));
```

Comment: D'oh. So obvious. Thanks.